# Laravel PHPunit kill process after test execution - PosgtreSQL max_connection exeed

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, testing, phpunit

I use PHPUnit do to several tests on a Laravel 5.4 application.

More than 100 tests use database queries. I use **\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations** class to reset and migrate database before each test (so for each method in test file).

But when I run **phpunit** command, it displays me an error which is due to max_connection was exeeded.

I can't increase max_connection limit on the server. I tried to use **--process-isolation** argument for phpunit but it increase the duration time of tests : 15 minutes instead 2 minutes.

I searched a lot of time a way to set a processes number limit but I don't found anything except **--process-isolation** argument.

Do you know a way to set process number for PHPUnit ? Or a way to remove DB connection after test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

I add this method to my **tests/TestCase.php** file :

```
public function tearDown() {
    \DB::connection()->setPdo(null);
}
```

By using this code, you should pay attention because parent tearDown() method will not run. You can add this line to do this :

```
parent::tearDown();
```

If, by adding this line, the problem persists, you should analyse parent tearDown() code to get the code which cause the problem.